# Error when checking : expected dense_3_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, anaconda

I am writing a neuron for determining the handwritten figures

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

json_file = open("mnist_model.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("mnist_model.h5")


loaded_model.compile(loss= "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])


img_path ="5.png"
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28,28), grayscale=True)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show

x =image.img_to_array(img)
x = 255 - x 
x/= 255
np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
prediction = loaded_model.predict(x)
prediction = np_utils.categorical_pobabs_to_classes(prediction)
print(prediction)
```

All I did was teach her to use it, but then the problem got out:
1.The result is a graph and an error `ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_3_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)` in Line ´img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28,28), grayscale=True)´

Comment: At which line did this error occur?

Comment: Line ´img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28,28), grayscale=True)´

Comment: Could you provide the image file?

Comment: @KenWei [link] (https://www.google.ru/search?q=mnist+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5iqK-mPzWAhUDJ5oKHT38AeQQ_AUICigB&biw=1350&bih=675#imgdii=sj08Q9EcrWfzBM:&imgrc=rU4Z5sMB-yONiM:)

Comment: ...... I'm quite conviced the error is in `loaded_model.predict(x)`. This is a very typical error. Your model expects shapes `(28,28)`, but you're passing input images with shape `(28,28,1)`. It's a matter of simply adjusting your `input_shape` accordingly in the model.

Comment: @StarLord can provide a dimension used for the input array(image) at  dense_3_input layer while training model?

Answer (score 0):

I think your fault is in this line

```
np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```

it should be:

```
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```